# How to get multiple conditionals to execute at the same time?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I decided to try to do a turtle project to learn the random commands. My question is in this code:

```
pos = 360
while a.ycor()<pos:
 a.forward(randint(1,5))
while b.ycor()<pos:
 b.forward(randint(1,5))
while c.ycor()<pos:
 c.forward(randint(1,5))
while d.ycor()<pos:
 d.forward(randint(1,5))
while e.ycor()<pos:
 e.forward(randint(1,5))
```

how can I get all the conditionals to execute at the same time to start the race (all turtles take off at the same time)?

Comment: So like `while condition1 and condition2 and condition3`, etc?

Comment: Can you explain what output do you want with the above code? Counting the forward steps is not enough?

Comment: You may want to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050438/how-to-move-multiple-turtles-at-the-same-time-in-python

Comment: Are you getting the output you want?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, so assuming you want to have multiple functions running at the same time, use either the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) or [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html) modules.
Quick multiprocessing example:

```
import multiprocessing, time

def aFunction(aVar):
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"Ye {aVar}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map(aFunction, [X for X in range(4)])
    input("Press Return to exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the logical operator `AND`:

```
pos = 360
while a.ycor()<pos and
      b.ycor()<pos and
      c.ycor()<pos and
      d.ycor()<pos and
      e.ycor()<pos:

     a.forward(randint(1,5))
     b.forward(randint(1,5))
     c.forward(randint(1,5))
     d.forward(randint(1,5))
     e.forward(randint(1,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repetition, you could have your variables and methods in a dictionary and then loop through them.

```
pos = 360

d = {a: a.ycor, b: b.ycor, c: c.ycor, d: d.ycor, e: e.ycor}

for k, v in d.items():
    while v() < pos:
        k.forward(randint(1, 5))
```