# Use turtle module to move turtles asynchronous

Tags: python, class, oop, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I would like to create, using turtle module, a robot that runs and after a while, to create another to run after the first one and so on. Basically:

- create first robot
- first robot moves
- while first robot still moves, create second robot
- second robot moves

And so on.

I have a class named Robot():

```
class Robot(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_car()
```

which has two methods: create_robot() that simply tells how the robot should look like and it position + direction:

```
    def create_robot(self):
        self.shape('square')
        self.setheading(180)
        self.penup()
        random_y = random.choice(range(-250, 250))
        self.goto(280, random_y)
```

The other method is:

```
def movement(self):
   self.forward(10)
```

After that, this while loop practically makes the robot move continously:

```
robot = Robot()
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(robot.movement(), t=10)
```

This creates only one robot that moves and is working properly.

Now, i want to create the second robot, by using an empty_list or different ways, but it seems that:

- More robots are created and they move synchronously
- More robots are created at different location but no one moves
- More robots created but only one moves (I assume the first robot created)

For creation of multiple robots I am using for loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    robot = Robot()
```

if I add in the while loop robot.create_robot(), it never reaches the robot.movement()

Comment: Can you share full code for your second robot? Avoid [`while game_is_on:` in Python turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352). There are many existing threads for moving multiple turtles at once, for example: [How to move multiple turtles at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050438/how-to-move-multiple-turtles-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Python Multiple Turtles Moving (seemingly) Simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056498/python-multiple-turtles-moving-seemingly-simultaneously?noredirect=1&lq=1). Do these answer your question?

Comment: `screen.ontimer(robot.movement(), t=10)` looks incorrect--you're calling that method immediately and passing its return value `None` into the `ontimer` call. You probably meant `screen.ontimer(robot.movement, t=10)`, which passes the method itself into `ontimer`, scheduling it to be invoked in the future, although if this fails due to an argument mismatch, you could use `screen.ontimer(lambda: robot.movement(), t=10)`. I also [discourage subclassing turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71003069/6243352).

Comment: using `screen.ontimer(robot.movement, t =10)` or adding lambda return error: `TypeError: TurtleScreen.ontimer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fun' `.

Comment: Unable to reproduce--that works for me locally with `from turtle import Screen;Screen().ontimer(lambda: print("OK"), t=1000);Screen().exitonclick()` (complete program; the print shows up after 1 second). Instead of disjointed fragments of code, please share your full code in a single code block so I can execute it easily.

Comment: The links kind of help, but I would require to make multiple robots, let's say 30. So is basically redundant to turn the tracer off for everyone. I saw the threads about moving synchronously, but I don't want that. Create robot, move, create another. Maybe is better to create all at once and then move a little bit each one so it seems that they are asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, it is doing it's job after a second (the print example) but what if i want to print Ok again? That's what I am looking for, to be able to move every robot created after a second.

Comment: I don't think it's redundant to disable tracer, although you can [turn it off for the whole app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979967/6243352), which it sounds like you want since you're writing a real time app. Moving each bot a little bit each time is the other approach.

Comment: My print example was just to show that the error you mentioned was not reproducible for me, not show how to run a continuous loop or solve your general problem. To run a continuous loop, call `ontimer` again from inside the `ontimer` callback as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65672087/6243352).

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a simple example based on your code that creates a small set of robots moving away from each other and occasionally spawning new robots in their own image:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randrange

class Robot(Turtle):
    BODIES = ('circle', 'triangle', 'square', 'turtle')

    def __init__(self, body, origin=(0, 0)):
        super().__init__(body, visible=False)
        self.create_robot(origin)

    def create_robot(self, origin):
        self.setheading(randrange(360))
        self.penup()
        self.goto(origin)
        self.showturtle()
        self.movement()

    def spawn(self):
        Robot(self.shape(), self.position())

    def movement(self):
        self.forward(1)
        screen.update()

        if randrange(1000) < 3:  # conditions are right to spawn
            self.spawn()

        width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()
        x, y = self.position()

        if -width//2 < x < width//2 and -height//2 < y < height//2:
            screen.ontimer(self.movement, 33)
        else:
            self.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

for body in Robot.BODIES:
    Robot(body)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Of course, this simple example wastes global turtle objects which aren't garbage collected.  In a real program we would save a list of these as they're deactivated and reuse an old one, if available, when a new one is spawned.