# how to thread multiple turtle heads in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-turtle

I made a recursive star for Art with Technology. My teacher wants me to make similar stars in 4 corners, I accomplished that too, but the screen recording is too big, hence I need them to run simultaneously, (currently they run after a star is completed). I tried threading but It does'nt do anything

Here is a minimal code:

```py
from turtle import *
import threading
from itertools import permutations
from random import choice
import concurrent.futures
screen=Screen()

def star_multiple(turtle):
    # repeatedly calls draw star function

def pen(foo):
    # a convenient tool to do all penup/pendown 

def drawstar(turtle,l,colors):
    # draws a star of edge=l param.

a,b,c,d=Turtle(),Turtle(),Turtle(),Turtle()

pen('penup')

a.goto(-500,200)# the turtle go to their position(works)
b.goto(500,200)
c.goto(-500,-200)
d.goto(500,-200)

pen('pendown')
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    executor.map(star_multiple,[a,b,c,d])# This doesn't work, 
done()
```

drawstar function

[image: a recursive star]

output I am getting

[image: 4 turtles]

Comment: I did it with daemon threads, but it still feels like its not that faster. maybe 3 seconds

Comment: The `turtle` module is implemented using `tkinter` which does not support multithreading — so you can't do what you want.

Comment: Why not disable tracer with `Screen().tracer(0)`, then use `Screen().update()` to draw everything instantly? If you want some animation, disable tracer and call `update()` repeatedly in a loop, with a little delay you determine yourself using `Screen().ontimer()`. Also possible is moving each one a little bit in alternation, as described in [How to move multiple turtles at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050438/how-to-move-multiple-turtles-at-the-same-time?noredirect=1&lq=1). Related: [Multithreading With Python Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498447)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move multiple turtles at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050438/how-to-move-multiple-turtles-at-the-same-time)