# Running two functions at the same time in Python Turtle?

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
from turtle import *
a = Screen()
b = Turtle()
c = Turtle()

def one():
    b.forward(100)
def two():
    c.forward(-100)
```

I want b and c moving away from each other at the same time, tried lots of stuff but I cant figure it out. Help me out please.

Comment: maybe you can try threading

Comment: this may be helpful :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time

Comment: I tried it but i couldnt make it work with turtle. Probably messed sm up, I'm new.

Comment: @gretal This should be duplicate of that link. This need to be closed. 

#icantcode you need to read again about threading and that link. Read thoroughly and try again. This should be closed as duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move multiple turtles at the same time in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050438/how-to-move-multiple-turtles-at-the-same-time-in-python)

Comment: i keep getting this error when i try to use threading.Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
main thread is not in main loop

Comment: That is a separate issue, [RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694408/runtimeerror-main-thread-is-not-in-main-loop), "You're running your main GUI loop in a thread besides the main thread. You cannot do this."

Comment: how do i fix it

Comment: Here's a multi-threading Turtle implementation for reference, [Multithreading With Python Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498447/multithreading-with-python-turtle) , "The turtle module can be used with threading if we carefully walk a tightrope where only the main thread issues turtle commands"

Comment: @icantcode, to fix it, see if below works or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multithreading With Python Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498447/multithreading-with-python-turtle)

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing all the code from [Multithreading With Python Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498447/multithreading-with-python-turtle), this appears to "work" for getting both functions to run at the same time.

If so, this is likely better a duplicate of linked answer.

```
import queue
import threading
import turtle

a = turtle.Screen()
b = turtle.Turtle()
c = turtle.Turtle()

def one():
    b.forward(100)
def two():
    c.forward(-100)

def process_queue():
    while not graphics.empty():
        (graphics.get())(1)

    if threading.active_count() > 1:
        turtle.ontimer(process_queue, 100)

graphics = queue.Queue(1)  # size = number of hardware threads you have - 1

turtle1 = turtle.Turtle('turtle')
turtle1.speed('fastest')
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=one)
thread1.daemon = True  # thread dies when main thread (only non-daemon thread) exits.
thread1.start()

turtle2 = turtle.Turtle('turtle')
turtle2.speed('fastest')
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=two)
thread2.daemon = True  # thread dies when main thread (only non-daemon thread) exits.
thread2.start()

turtle.mainloop()
```